# Zend 2 and auth configuration routing

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

I'm working curently on a Zend2 project where there is an authentifaction system for the whole website, it was fine until we had to develop a module which is an public web service.

I would like to know if it's possible to allow users to access to a specific module/routing of Zend 2 ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to use `Zend\Authentication\Adapter\Http`. I have written a tutorial before some time. You can read it from here. If necessary I will create an answer explaining it in more depth. http://learnzf2.sitrun-tech.com/learn-zf2-authentication

Answer (score 0):

`The Zend\Authentication\Adapter\Http` provides an easy way for Apache like authentication in Zend Framework 2 applications.

It comes with two implementations Basic and Digest HTTP Authentication, which can be combined with two sub components - the class itself or a FileResolver. We are going to use the FileResolver to read the stored credentials and compare them to the submitted values.

First thing first. There are few important things to know.

1. Create a folder with name auth in MODULE_NAME/config/. Inside that folder create two files basic.txt and digest.txt. The file formats are smillar to Apache .htpasswd files.
   `Basic - <username>:<realm>:<credentials>`, here credentials should be written in clear text, e.g.: `basic:authentication:plaintextpassword`. 
   `Digest - <username>:<realm>:<credentials>, where <credentials>` is the md5 hash of all 3 parts, e.g.: `digest:authentication:dc45122ef294d83e84a8b5a3a6c5356b`
2. In the same module, where we have just created our auth folder, open module.config.php file and place this code.

The code tells us which authentication schemes we accept, the realm (must be the same as the realm in the basic/digest.txt files, digest_domains (only when we use digest authentication) is the URL(s) where we want to apply the same valid information, nonce_timeout sets the number of seconds for which the nonce is valid.

```
/**
 * Used for basic authentication
 */
'authentication_basic' => [
    'adapter' => [
        'config' => [
            'accept_schemes' => 'basic',
            'realm'          => 'authentication',
            'nonce_timeout'  => 3600,
        ],
        'basic'  => __DIR__.'/auth/basic.txt',
    ],
],
/**
 * Used for digest authentication
 */
'authentication_digest' => [
    'adapter' => [
        'config' => [
            'accept_schemes' => 'digest',
            'realm'          => 'authentication',
            'digest_domains' => '/learn-zf2-authentication/digest',
            'nonce_timeout'  => 3600,
        ],
        'digest' => __DIR__.'/auth/digest.txt',
    ],
]
```

**LearnZF2Authentication\Factory\BasicAuthenticationAdapterFactory**

```
  $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
    $authConfig = $config['authentication_basic']['adapter'];
    $authAdapter = new HttpAdapter($authConfig['config']);

    $basic = new FileResolver();
    $basic->setFile($authConfig['basic']);

    $authAdapter->setBasicResolver($basic);

    return $authAdapter;
```

**LearnZF2Authentication\Factory\DigestAuthenticationAdapterFactory**

```
    $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
    $authConfig = $config['authentication_digest']['adapter'];
    $authAdapter = new HttpAdapter($authConfig['config']);

    $digest = new FileResolver();
    $digest->setFile($authConfig['digest']);

    $authAdapter->setDigestResolver($digest);

    return $authAdapter;
```

These are the codes we use to pass the authentication information

**Module.php**

```
/**
 * @var MvcEvent $e
 */
$request  = $e->getRequest();
$response = $e->getResponse();
$view = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$authAdapter = $sm->get('LearnZF2Authentication\BasicAuthenticationAdapter');

/**
 * Not HTTP? Stop!
 */
if (!($request instanceof Http\Request && $response instanceof Http\Response)) {
    return;
}

/**
 * Call the factory class and try to authenticate
 */
if ($e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action') == 'digest') {
    $authAdapter = $sm->get('LearnZF2Authentication\DigestAuthenticationAdapter');
}
$authAdapter->setRequest($request);
$authAdapter->setResponse($response);

if($e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action') == 'basic' || $e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action') == 'digest') {
    $result = $authAdapter->authenticate();

    /**
     * Pass the information to the view and see what we got
     */
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        return $view->identity = $result->getIdentity();
    } else {
        /**
         * Create a log function or just use the one from LearnZF2.
         * Also make sure to redirect to another page, 404 for example
         */
        foreach ($result->getMessages() as $msg) {
            return $view->authProblem = $msg;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code we use to pass the authentication information

One last important thing to note is that you must include a special header called Authorization n your request, replace :

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

with

PHP compiled as CGI does not support apache_response_headers function, but we need this header in order to do basic HTTP authtentication when running with CGI or FastCGI.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%    {HTTP:Authorization},L,NC]
```

and add in top of public/index.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER["REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"])) {
   $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"];
}
```

Some things to note. The auth folder as well the authentication code from module.config.php is best to be placed in your main config folder, where the global|local.php files are and excluded from commits.

Comment: @user3045808 if this answer solved your problem then you can click the check mark to mark it as accepted.